# Does 'reason' have a modifier and a complement?

Tags: complementation, licensing

> Things couldn't have been worse. 
>       Filch took them down to Professor McGonagall's study on the first floor, where they sat and waited without saying a word to each other.
>   Hermione was trembling. Excuses, alibis, and wild cover-up stories
>   chased each other around Harry's brain, each more feeble than the
>   last. He couldn't see how they were going to get out of trouble this
>   time. They were cornered. How could they have been so stupid as to
>   forget the cloak? There was no **reason** on earth **that** Professor
>   McGonagall would accept **for** their being out of bed and creeping
>   around the school in the dead of night, let alone being up the tallest
>   astronomy tower, which was out-of-bounds except for classes.
>   (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Does the ‘reason’ license that-clause as its modifier and for-phrase as its complement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *that* is a relative clause and does not require licensing.

The *for* clause, however, is as you say a complement. *Reason* licenses clausal complements of several types:

- a reason for going
- a reason for them going
- a reason for their going
- a reason to go
- a reason for them to go